# Is there a way to center a set all images in a grid to the same size

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a fake desktop app for "Pentel", using electron, and I put a few images of pens in a grid. So far, this is what the app looks like:

[image: Site]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f5dc;
}

.nav-bar {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3em;
}


.nav-bar .logo {
  height: 5vh;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

.pens-images {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  max-width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  gap: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="./images/pentel_logo.png" class="logo">
      </a>
    </nav>
    
      <div class="pens-images">
        <img src="./images/black-energel-rtx-refillable-liquid-gel-pen.png" alt="black EnerGel RTX refillable liquid gel pen">
        <img src="./images/blue-ballpoint-07-clear-barrel.png" alt="blue ballpoint 0.7 clear barell pen">
        <img src="./images/EnerGel-X-retractable-gel-pen.png" alt="EnerGel-X retractable gel pen">
        <img src="./images/tradio-fountaion-blue-ink-white-barrel-pen.png" alt="tradio fountain blue ink white barrel pen">
      </div>
    
  </body>
```

I want to put the grid in the center and make all images the same width and height, how can I do that?

Comment: You should use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 1):

`auto` value rather means not assigning any grid specific logic to the element = elements have the size they want.

To make similar columns with css grid this pattern should work in most cases

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.pens-images {
width:  100px;
height: 100px;
place-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class. And that class add
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

```
.pens-images {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  max-width: 70%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));;
  gap: 0.5em;
}
```